# Sorting Nodes in LINKED LIST by alphabet by comparing Strings stored in each Node. (C program)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STR_LEN 80

//STRUCT
typedef struct link_node
{
char node_str[MAX_STR_LEN];
struct link_node *next;
} link;

// FUNCTION CALLS
link *Nodes_Create(int num);
int compare_node(link *n1, link *n2);
link *add_node(link *list, link *node);
void display_list(link *head);

//MAIN
int main() {
    int num, i;
    link *Head;
    link *Rest;
    link *Temp;

    printf("how many users? ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    getchar(); //DEBUGGING

    Head = Nodes_Create(num);
    display_list(Head);

    //COMPARE
    Rest = Head;
    for(i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
        if(compare_node(Rest, Rest->next) == -1) {  //for example: 28->17->08->54
            printf("\nTRUE");
            Temp = Rest->next;
            Rest->next = Rest; //NOT WORKING!!!
            Rest = Temp;
        }
        else printf("\nFALSE");
        Rest = Rest->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
//FUNCTION FOR CREATING NODES
link *Nodes_Create(int num) {
    link *Temp = NULL;
    link *Head = NULL;
    link *Rest = NULL;
    char userName[MAX_STR_LEN];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        //ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR TEMP NODE
        Temp = (link*)malloc(sizeof(link));
        //GET STRING IN TEMP->node_str
        printf("Enter the user name for user N%d: ", i + 1);
        fgets(userName, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);
        strcpy(Temp->node_str, userName);
        Temp->next = NULL;

        //CREATING NODES
        if (Head == NULL) {
            Head = Temp;
        }
        else {
            Rest = Head;
            while(Rest->next != NULL) {
                Rest = Rest->next;
            }
            Rest->next = Temp;
        }
    }
    return Head;
}
//FUNCTION FOR COMPARING NODES
int compare_node(link *n1, link *n2) {
    link* Temp;

    if(n1->node_str[0] > n2->node_str[0])
        return -1;
    else if(n1->node_str[0] == n2->node_str[0])
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
//FUNCTION FOR ADDING NODES
link *add_node(link *list, link *node) {

}
//FUNCTION FOR DISPLAYING NODES
void display_list(link *head) {
    link *rest = head;

    while(rest != NULL){
        printf("%s", rest->node_str);
        rest = rest->next;
    }
}
```

> Hello, this is my code for the homework I have in compe160 course, but I can't figure out how to alphabetically arrange strings in my linked list, so if I have 4 inputs: Mike, Bob, Ann, Jacob. I would like it to be arranged as follows: Ann, Bob, Jacob, Mike. problem here is in //COMPARE section of my code in main() everything else works fine.
> Temp = Rest->next;
> Rest->next = Rest;
> Rest = Temp;
> This above code is not working and I don't understand why, if someone would explain it to me I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance. Also it's my first time posting here and I don't know how to properly do it :DD

Comment: c#, c++ and c are three very different languages. Please don't spam unrelated tags

Comment: Take a piece of paper and draw a box for temp and a box for rest. Now do each of your operations in turn. Where do Rest and Temp point to now? Where do their next pointers point to?

Comment: I clicked recommended tags :// will keep in mind next time

Comment: they point to same thing...? Rest would point to (Rest->next)->next; Temp points to same thing I think. Am not very good at this just started learning. @Botje

Answer (score 0):

Let us start by drawing a picture of the linked list:

```
prev -> c1=Rest -> c2 -> Tail
```

Here, `Rest` points to `c1`, and you have determined that `c1` and `c2` are in the wrong order. That means we want to establish that `prev->next = c2`, `c2->next = c1`, and `c1->next = Tail`.

Ignoring `prev` for a moment, the last two are easy to do:

```
link* Tail = c2->next;
c2->next = c1; /* We now have c2 -> c1 -> c2 -> ... */
c1->next = Tail; /* c2 -> c1 -> tail */
Rest = c2; /* so Rest = Rest->next points to c1 -> Tail */
```

Your current code does not have a `prev` so we cannot fix up *that* link.
Worse, it could be that the very first two cells of the list need to be swapped, so we *also* need to update your `Head` pointer.

There is common trick for this that involves keeping a pointer to a pointer to the linked list: at the first iteration, `link** prev = &Head`, and for every iteration after that `prev = &Rest->next;`

We can now add the following to the block above:

```
*prev = c2;
```

and things will work out in all cases.

Comment: I will try fixing up my code as soon as I get back to my pc. Thanks nonetheless.